# How to configure apache virtual host to support these variables?

Tags: php, header

First, let me say that I am not a coder. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have been attempting work with php code snippets found here to build a simple web page that does two things" 1) Display an initial graphic first (png/jpg) and 2) display/list info in plain text about the client ip address and various other connection info. Some of the variables work but some don't.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST`
`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR`
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  ->> This one works by default
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

When I use these variables above, the results are always blank. What needs to be set/configured on the apache side to make these variables work?
Looking for starting points to research.

Thank you,
Jay

Comment: There is nothing you need to configure to use those variables. They are only filled of it makes sense, however. Maybe you do not have a ServerName assigned to your http host? And there is no routable IP address the server can consider "it's" address?

Comment: And you make requests to `server1.adcfun.com` that are then served by that host?

Comment: Correction. I have this simple entry now in my server1.conf file /var/www.

Comment: `/var/www` is not a `ServerName` value, but a path.

Comment: My apologies for deleting the first comment. I wanted to edit it. Yes, I am hitting it by name and ip.  I have an entry in my local hosts file. Also, I just meant that the server1.conf is in my /var/www directory. The web page does load, it is just that the results are blank.

Comment: arkascha, your very first comment got me thinking. I have switched a different sample of code and I am getting closer. Thank you for the clarification.